# What location is this and what does it signify - "d:\w7rtm\minkernel\ntdll\ldrinit.c"

Tags: malware

Came across this while debugging a exe. Cant find much on it anywhere so thought I'll put it up here. Any ideas as to what this could be used for?

CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
77887F10   .  64 3A 5C 77 3 ASCII "d:\w7rtm\minkern"                 ; ASCII "d:\w7rtm\minkernel\ntdll\ldrinit.c"

Comment: how is it a duplicate? completely different path...

Comment: This is not malware. That is most certainly a path to the Windows source code files where that build of Windows was compiled from. For instance in the symbols for `ntdll.dll` for Windows 10 now, there's a lot of debugging strings that give the following folder as the location of their source files: `"minkernel\ntdll\*****"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a path that you might find in a checked (== with assertions) build of Windows 7 as a source path in the output of failed assertions. However, it could be a fake to make something appear more legit. You're tagging the question as [malware](/questions/tagged/malware) but I don't quite see the connection.

Given the path it would not be inconceivable to think that this is some code that uses an older version of `ntdll.dll` loaded by another name. Stranger things have happened, such as loading a second `ntoskrnl.exe` to dodge a possibly patched *running* kernel.

Anyway the RTM in `w7rtm` means release to manufacturer and refers to the very first release version of a Windows. And given that this refers to Windows 7, this is *several* years old by now.